# How to show something is well-defined?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus

As I was going through real analysis book I have seen many things are defined but not well-defined , how can I show that something is well-defined for example how should i show that image of a function f; X->Y
 is defined as im(f) := {y ∈ Y ; ∃x ∈ X : y = f(x)} ?
How can I show that it is well-defined , anyone could help me I will remain thankful .

Answer (score 0):

Well-defined means there is a unique one of them.  In your example, assuming $f$ is a well-defined function the image of $f$ is also well-defined.  In set theory we can appeal to the axiom of replacement to show that.  $X$ is a set, so we can replace each element $x \in X$ with $f(x)$ and get the new set $Y$.

Answer (score 0):

In your example the right side is uniquely determined by f so is automatically well defined . But suppose for each positive real number x you defined 
g(x) to be a real number y satisfying $y^2=x$  . Well defined means you can change the word  "a" to "the" . But for example if x=4 you want to find y with $y^2=4$ The problem is that there are 2  such y ,namely y=2 and y=-2 and you haven't said which you should take . So g is not  well defined ;in other words it is not a properly defined function . 
 To fix this change the definition to g(x) = the real number y with y positive and and $y^2=x Now as I have anticipated by writing "the" in the definition .Of course g is the square root . Some think that the square root of 4 is either +2 or -2 But then square root would not be considered a well defined (or single valued ) function. In modern times the word function always means single valued (or well defined function)  Multiple valued functions are handled as set valued functions (which are single valued and well defined ) .